# Getting user specified information from URL in Objective C iOS

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, hyperlink

Currently I am working with a UIWebview which shows web content provided from a user. In this content there will be links to other web content and I need to decide whether to open links in safari or in the UIWebview.

My current solution is to add a queryString to the URL in the html e.g. `<a href=http://www.w3schools.com?StayInApp target=_blank>Visit W3Schools</a>`

When the user presses the link the following method in the UIViewController decides how to open the link.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  NSURL *url = [request URL];
  NSLog(@"%@",url);
  NSLog(@"%@",[url scheme]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[url user]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[url query]);

  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {


    if ([[url query]isEqualToString:@"OutOfAppApp"]) {
        NSLog(@"go out");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

        return NO;
    }
    else if([[url query]isEqualToString:@"StayInApp"])
    {
        return YES;
    }
  }

  return YES;
}
```

I do not have very much experience within web development and can therefore not see the consequences of using this approach. Is this a valid approach or should I use another way?

Regards

**EDIT:** 
I have now come up with another approach using custom URL schemes, but I would still like comments on whether this is a valid solution :)

I have added a prefix to the links such as `<a href=InAPP:http://www.w3schools.com target=_blank>Visit W3Schools</a>`
When a user presses a link the app examines the prefix and decides whether to launch the rest of the url in the app or in safari. This is done with the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        NSURL *url = [request URL];

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        if ([[url scheme]isEqualToString:@"InAPP"]) {
            NSLog(@"go in");
            NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self removeExtensionFromURL:url]];
            [[self browserView] loadRequest:req];
            return NO;
        }
        else if([[url scheme]isEqualToString:@"OutAPP"])
        {
             NSLog(@"go out");
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[self removeExtensionFromURL:url]];

            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

    -(NSURL*)removeExtensionFromURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSMutableString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSString *newURLString;

    if ([[url scheme]isEqualToString:@"InAPP"]) {
       newURLString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"InAPP:" withString:@""];
    }
    else if([[url scheme]isEqualToString:@"OutAPP"])
    {
    newURLString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"OutAPP:" withString:@""];
    }
    return [NSURL URLWithString:newURLString];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use custom URL scheme for this? See  http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: I need at least two different schemes to decide whether is should in the app or in safari so I do not believe this is the way to go

Comment: Actually I am now working with schemes where i append InAPP: to the link such as <a href=InAPP:http://www.w3schools.com?StayInApp target=_blank>Visit W3Schools</a> After the user presses the link the app decides what to do depending on the scheme.